# E: unable to locate package update (Android Termux)

Tags: android, termux, mining, monero

I followed the directions here: https://gist.github.com/2niuhe/f9c0a1168ebc02bd0b89ffdb7ed21f6c to try and get a working version of XMRig on my Android, but sadly it's failing at the first step. Can somebody help? These are the commands it instructs me to run:

```
pkg install update && upgrade
apt install git
apt install wget
apt install proot
termux-setup-storage
git clone https://github.com/Neo-Oli/termux-ubuntu
cd termux-ubuntu
chmod +x ubuntu.sh
sh ubuntu.sh
./start-ubuntu.sh
```

Comment: and whats the output when you run them? What issue are you facing?

Comment: Use apt update instead of pkg